# SSIS Script Task move all files not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I'm using a Script Task (C#) within SSIS to move all .txt files from one folder to another.  However, when I execute this, nothing happens.  The Script Task actually reports success but the text files do not move.  I'm using variables for all the paths - they all start with 2 backslashes and end with 1 back slash.

All I want to do is move all text files from the source destination to the destination folder.

What am I missing?

```
public void Main()
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Dts.Variables["IN_Folder"].Value.ToString());

            string destinationFolder = Dts.Variables["User::IN_Folder_Processing"].Value.ToString();
            string sourceFolder = Dts.Variables["User::IN_Folder"].Value.ToString();


            FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles("*.txt");
            String filename = fi[0].Name;

            string sourceFileName = filename;
            string destinationFile = destinationFolder + sourceFileName;
            string sourceFile =sourceFolder + sourceFileName;

            if (File.Exists(destinationFile))
                File.Delete(destinationFile);
            // To move a file or folder to a new location:
            System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

Comment: Pause the code in the debugger and confirm that the values for `sourceFile` and `destinationFile` are what you expect when it runs.

Comment: They do - sourcefile and destination have the full folder path and file name

Comment: Why use a Script Task? Wouldn't a For Each Container and a File System Task be far easier?

Comment: possibly yes, but I would have thought the above should have still worked.

Comment: If your paths are all variables, are you escaping the \ characters? Double up all the backslashes and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by escaping the `` characters?

Comment: If you get the code right, yes, it'll work, but why re-invent the wheel? A for Each Container and File System Task will be far easier to create (no code required) and likely far easier to debug as the errors will be presented to you in the Output/Result pane.

Comment: Backslashes need to be escaped when putting them into a variable. So `\\server\folder\file.txt` would become `\\\\server\\folder\\file.txt`.

Comment: I doubt that is going to be relevant @digital.aaron. If the values are variables then c#/SSIS will handle the values inside the variable accordingly. Yes, when passed a literal value to an expression in SSIS you need to double up a backslash (`\\\\MyFileServer\\MyShare\\MyFile.txt`) but the variable won't have those double up values in it.

Comment: the variables are like this: \\server\share\folder\subfolder\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like I mentioned in the comments, there seems to be no need to use a Script Task to do this; a far better option would be a Foreach Loop Container and a FileSystem Task.

Firstly create the Foreach Loop Container, open the editor and go to the Collection Pane. Change Enumerator to Foreach File Enumerator. I assume you are using a variable for the directory, so click `...` for Expressions and select Directory for the Property and your variable for the expression.

As you specifically want to deal with txt files, change Files to `*.txt`. What option you use for Retreive File Name depends on how your determining the destination. I'm going to assume you have another variable with the directory target, so select `Name and extention`.

Go to the Variable Mappings pane and select your filename variable, or create a new one. Leave the Index as `0`. This will store the Name and extension of the file you are going to move.

Create a new variable in your package, called `OriginalFilePath`, or something easily identifiable. Set the value to `string` and then change the Scope to your Foreach Loop Container. Now open the expression pane for the variable and set the expression to something like:

```
@[User::SourceDirectoryVariable] + "\\" + @[User::FileNameVariable]
```

Obviously change the variable names to what they need to be. Now create a second variable (same settings), however, using your destination directory variable instead of the source (`@[User::DestinationDirectoryVariable] + "\\" + @[User::FileNameVariable]`).

Now, in your Control Flow, create a File System Task within your Foreach Loop Container. Change Operation to Move File. Then fill in the rest of the pane as needed (`IsSourceVariable` will be True, and then select your variable). Do the same for the destination, and then you *should* be good to go.

Any problems, please do comment **with** the error.

Comment: Thanks for this.  On the Collection \ Enumerator config \ Folder - do I leave this as the Expressions will overwrite it?  Also on the Variable Mappings is this the destination filepath?

Comment: Provided your variable has a value, the value of `Folder` should automatically update. In regards to Variable Mappings, no, it's the source file path (you *are* looping over your source files after all).

Comment: Great thanks. I will check tomorrow when back in the office

Comment: Why do I need the @[User::FileNameVariable] variable?  I do not know the files name as they are 'dumped' in the folder - I only know they are all .txt files?

Comment: Where else are you going to store the name of the file you're going to move other than in a variable, @Michael ..? Computers/programs don't work, like people. you can say "find a list of files in a directory" and then say "Move it here", without giving it context of what "it" is ("it" in this case, being the file, which you need to specify to the application).

Comment: But when I create the variable in Visual Studio - what actual value do I assign to it or do I just leave it blank?

Comment: The Foreach Loop Container assigns the value, @Michael . That's what the Variable Mapping is doing. it doesn't need a default value. I'm defined the steps to be quite explicit; you *shouldn't* need to do anything to items I don't tell you to do.

Comment: its working.  We got there in the end!  Many thanks.

Comment: Glad you got there @Michael. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid manually concatenating file paths using the `string` + operator. This leaves a lot of room for error. Use `System.IO.Path.Combine()`. This ensures all leading and trialing slashes are formatted properly.

There's also no need to rebuild the file paths manually using all those additional variables. Something like this will work just fine so long as your input variable directories are correct:

```
public void Main()
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Dts.Variables["IN_Folder"].Value.ToString());
        string destinationFolder = Dts.Variables["User::IN_Folder_Processing"].Value.ToString();
        FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles("*.txt");

        foreach (FileInfo f in fi)
        {
            FileInfo destinationFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(destinationFolder, f.Name));
            if (destinationFile.Exists)
                destinationFile.Delete();
            f.MoveTo(destinationFile.FullName);
        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```